# audio does not play after pressing button in iphone safari

Tags: reactjs, safari, web-audio-api

I have a react component that has a button with a handler to play an audio.

```
  const initializeAudio = () => {
    let context = new AudioContext()
    let analyser = context.createAnalyser()
    let audioSrc = context.createMediaElementSource(audioRef.current)
    audioSrc.connect(analyser)
    analyser.connect(context.destination)
    analyser.fftSize = 512
    setAnalyser(analyser)
  }

  const play = () => {
    if (!audioSet) {
      initializeAudio()
      setAudioSet(true)
      audioRef.current.volume = 0.5
    }
    audioRef.current.play()
    setPlaying(true)
    interval = window.setInterval(turnToTime, 1000)
  }
```

```html
<audio
            data-keepplaying
            ref={audioRef}
            id="audioElement"
            src={audio}
          />
          <WaveForm analyser={analyser} />
          <button onClick={isPlaying ? pause : play} className="media_button">
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              className="fa-icon"
              icon={isPlaying ? "pause" : "play"}
              style={!isPlaying && { paddingLeft: "0.4rem" }}
            ></FontAwesomeIcon>
          </button>
```

Everything works fine on firefox and chrome, but won't work on safari on iphone, any one know why?

I feel that my audio is created in response to a click which is what the new restriction needed, but why is safari not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading your code I would guess that the second line is throwing an error in Safari. Safari still has no official support for the Web Audio API and the `AudioContext` is only available as `webkitAudioContext`.

If initializing the context is your only concern using the following technique might work.

```
let context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
```

However I would not recommend using it as it treats Safari's implementation similar to the one in Firefox or Chrome even though they differ in many aspects. As I'm the author of [standardized-audio-context](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/standardized-audio-context) using this package is of course my preferred way to handle inconsistent browser support for the Web Audio API. :-)

You can use it like this.

```
import { AudioContext } from 'standardized-audio-context';

let context = new AudioContext();
```

I hope this helps.